# JQuery use with complicated selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

thanks beforehand for the help.
I tried to Manipulated a [calendar existing airline tickets web page](https://www.turkishairlines.com/).
In a way which giving a input of start Date and end Date to a function and she will search on the calendar the current pages and click the correct day element.
my main problem is with the jquery selector i use when i try merge a month and a day which i dont know before the call and therefore the jquery dont recognize my mix of vars i made:

```
  var sDateVar = MONTH_NAMES[startDate[1]]+ ' ' +startDate[0];
  $("[aria-label=sDateVar]").click();
```

thats the whole code:

```
/**
* A function to select start date and end date from Turkish Airlines
* website
* Assumption: The date-picker is already in an open position when running
* the code
* @param {String} startDate - with format dd/mm/yyyy
* @param {String} endDate - with format dd/mm/yyyy
* @returns {Boolean} success or not
*/
Function selectDateInTurkishAirlines(startDate, endDate){

  //months names for later convert
  const MONTH_NAMES = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  //split the dates in different vars  for easy use.
  var startDate = startDate.Split('/');
  var endDate = endDate.Split('/');


  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  var nextClicksForStart = 12*(startDate[2]-yyyy) + (startDate[1]-mm);
  var nextClicksForEnd = 12*(endDate[2]-startDate[2]) + (endDate[1]-startDate[1]);


  var sDateVar = MONTH_NAMES[startDate[1]]+ ' ' +startDate[0];
  var eDateVar = MONTH_NAMES[endDate[1]]+ ' ' +endDate[0];
  //move to the current startDate month on the calendar and click the startDate
  for (var nextCountS = 0; nextCountS < nextClicksForStart; nextCountS++) {
    $("[data-handler='next']").click();
  }
  $("[aria-label=sDateVar]").click();
  //move to the current endDate month on the calendar and click the endDate
  for (var nextCountE = 0; nextCountE < nextClicksForEnd; nextCountE++) {
    $("[data-handler='next']").click();
  }
  $("[aria-label=eDateVar").click();
}
```

thanks again for any help or new direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating variables for the selectors, but aren't using them in the selectors:.

Example:

```
var myVar = 'something';
// you are doing like
$("[data-handler=myVar]");

// when you should be doing like
$("[data-handler=" + myVar + "]");
// which will be equivalent to $("[data-handler=something]");
```

Of course, mind the value of these variables. If they have `"` or `]`, it may make the selector invalid. If that's a possibility, quote the selector:

```
$("[data-handler='" + myVar + "']");
```

Again, in this example, you are assuming the variable does not have a `'`.

Some of your code, updated:

```
  var sDateVar = MONTH_NAMES[startDate[1]]+ ' ' +startDate[0];
  var eDateVar = MONTH_NAMES[endDate[1]]+ ' ' +endDate[0];
  //move to the current startDate month on the calendar and click the startDate
  for (var nextCountS = 0; nextCountS < nextClicksForStart; nextCountS++) {
    $("[data-handler='next']").click();
  }
  $("[aria-label='" + sDateVar + "']").click(); // changed
  //move to the current endDate month on the calendar and click the endDate
  for (var nextCountE = 0; nextCountE < nextClicksForEnd; nextCountE++) {
    $("[data-handler='next']").click();
  }
  $("[aria-label='"+ eDateVar + "']").click(); // changed
```

Comment: Those `for` loops make no sense either

Comment: Maybe he wants to paginate ahead by clicking next many times.

Comment: Not sure what is expected but regardless as they stand now they do the same thing in every iteration which is pointless

Comment: It could be an arrow, for next page. It makes sense clicking on it N times to go forward N pages, no?

Comment: Actually, that's precisely what it is, an arrow that moves months forward on a datepicker. I just checked.

Comment: yep i called the next page N times until i reached the correct month. and thanks acdcjunior

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand pretty much your problem but I see things that you can fix there.

`$('[arial-label="' + sDateVar + '"]')`

also here:

`$('[aria-label="' + eDateVar + '"]')`

another thing: shouldn't be the `.click()` call be changed for a `.trigger('click')` because I think that you want to emulate a click there, right?

Comment: yes i just did it worng in JQuery selector i didn't understood that i need to creat a whole selector and not only part. thanks guys.